# Sort and group a list of objects by multiple properties and conditions

Tags: c#, linq, sql-order-by

I have a list of objects that have the following properties:

Date (regular date format)
High Priority (boolen)
Priority (integer)
Completed (boolean)
Close (boolean)

I am trying to use linq to order this list to the following logic:

Order by high priority if not completed 
then by priority if not completed 
then by no priority 
then by high priority if completed 
then by priority if completed 
then by closed

Also I need each of the grouping to be ordered by date.

Here is my current linq query:

```
Tasks.GroupBy(x => x.Date)
    .Select(s => 
        s.OrderByDescending(a => a.HighPriority)
         .ThenBy(a => a.Priority)
         .ThenBy(a => a.Closed))
    .SelectMany(sa => sa)
    .ToList();
```

How do I change my query to get a list to follow my logic?

Comment: I would order before grouping since grouping will maintain order.  Not sure why you are using SelectMany which is removing the Group by Date.  A groupby creates a two dimensional array <key,List<object>>.  The SelectMany is flattening the two dimensional array to List<object>.  So your final results does not look like the order is working.

Comment: You can use a dynamic type and add a new column called orderpriority which you'd populate according to your logic, and then orderby orderpriority.

Comment: I don't understand why are you grouping by date if you only need to order

Comment: I'm not totally sure what I am doing. My query is a combination of multiple sources. That is why I ended up asking my own question. All the comments saying "i don't understand why you are..." don't help me.

Comment: explain me the "if not completed part", as long as you order, if it isn't completed in the first check, it probably won't be in the second too

Comment: @EdPlunkett if his needs aren't clear it isn't my fault

Comment: @MarcoSalerno Autocomplete filled in the wrong username starting with "M", and I missed it. My bad.

Comment: @MatthewCzajka The "I don't understand why you are..." comments are meant to help them understand your problem.

Comment: I am trying to order by high priority when completed is false, then priority when completed is false, then when priority is empty, then high priority when completed is true. I guess my main overall question is how to order off of two of the properties.

Comment: if high priority is true & completed is false, then if priority is not null & completed is false, then if priority is null, then if priority is true & completed is true, then if priority is not null & completed is true

Comment: @MatthewCzajka as i stated what are you doing is logically wrong, can you explain us why are you doing that?

Comment: I did a group by because i wanted each group to be ordered by date. but then I did a select for the actual list order I wanted. I understand im logically wrong, thats why im asking for help on how to change it

Comment: When you say "I need each of the grouping to be ordered by date" what does that mean? You don't have any groups, you have a sort order specified. What are your groups? You are already ordering by priority, how do you expect to order by date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Tasks` is a collection of instances of a class. Create a calculated property in that class called `OrderPriority`.

```
public byte OrderPriority
{
    get
    {
        if (HighPriority && !Completed)
            return 1;
        if (Priority && !Completed)
            return 2;
        // and so forth
    }
}
```

Then your LINQ could look like:

```
Tasks.OrderBy(x => x.OrderPriority).ThenBy(x => x.Date).ToList();
```